# How to filter data through awk or grep to get the time only?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, json

```
curl -H Metadata:true --noproxy "*" "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/compute/tagsList? 
api-version=2019-06-04"|
```

Through the above command I'm getting out put like below

```
root@puppetagent-ubuntu1:/home/azureuser# grep -i "shutdown_time" test.txt  |awk '/value/{print}' |jq

[ { "name": "Application_Name", "value": "POC-Exception" }, { "name": "Cost_Center", "value": "1000501541" }, { "name": "Stage", "value": "POC" }, { "name": "shutdown_time", "value": "16:00 [IST]" } ]
```

So I want to filter where time and time zones are like IST or PST in value but in this where time is not fixed and time zone is not fixed. Please help me.

Comment: Please provide us the expected output. Your english is a bit difficult to understand, maybe you can try to fix it a bit, so we can understand correctly.

Comment: Expected output is "16:00" for now but the value will be changing based on system tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jq`:

```
$ ... | jq -r '.[]|select(.name == "shutdown_time").value'
16:00 [IST]

$ ... | jq -r '.[]|select(.name == "shutdown_time").value' | cut -d' ' -f1
16:00
```

Comment: How to remove square bracket through the "cut" command if the input is [16:00]?

Comment: you don't use the `cut` for it, rahter `sed` or `awk` then.

Comment: ... you could also consider additional filtering inside jq ex. `|split(" ")[0]` in the first case or `|sub("[][]";"";"g")` for the remove brackets case

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr pLumo & Steeldriver for the help above .